# Else clause (in if statement) not executing 

Tags: java

```
 public class Funny {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
    int n=5;
    if (n==5);{
    System.out.println("welcome");
    }
    else if (n<5);{
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}
}
}
```

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token Funny.java  /Hello Woood/src    line 15 Java Problem
```

Comment: If an answer helped, click the checkmark to accept it. This tells others the question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

You have semi-colons after your if statements.

You want

```
if(n==5) {
    code();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically what is happening is that the

```
if (n==5);
```

is interpreted as a statement on its own.  Something like "is n equal to 5? if so, then cool, whatever"

The next statement now has nothing to do with the if. It is an anonymous block and is executed as is:

```
{
  System.out.println("welcome");
}
```

The 'else' after the statement now makes no sense to java as there is no if statement to link it to (the first one is completed because of the ;). Therefor the syntax error.

Another often overlooked pitfall with ; is:

```
while (n==5); {
    System.out.println("n is still 5, let's make it more..."); 
    n++;
}
```

In this example, you'll either get an infinite loop (n is 5 and will never change) or you'll get the printout "n is still 5..." (even though n is NOT 5 at this point).  It will then be incremented.  Very confusing and all of that because of a ; that separates the block from the while-loop.

As everyone said before me..., remove the ;.

Hope this helps... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `;` between the if-statements' condition and the opening curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the ; after the if and after the else statement. If you remove only the ; after the if statement, you code will ever execute  System.out.println("world");